# Invalid column name for non-existent column or property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework to save a record to the Address table of our SQL Server database, but upon the call to context.SaveChanges, I get an exception saying "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."  Upon inspection of the inner exception, there's a message, "Invalid column name 'Telephone_TelephoneID'."

The Address table does not have a "TelephoneID" column.  It may have had one at one time, but we're sure we removed any trace of it; there's no mention of such a column in any keys, constraints, or indexes of the Address table.  The entity class for an address record, an instance of which I add to the context, has no "TelephoneID" property.  The Telephone table does have a "TelephoneID" column, but I'm not involving it or its entity class in any way.

Where could this error possibly be coming from?  Thanks in advance...

EDIT -- While debugging and watching the context object, we noticed that the Addresses property evaluates as:

```
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], 
[Extent1].[AddressTypeID] AS [AddressTypeID], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID], 
[Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Extent1].[County] AS [County], 
[Extent1].[Extra] AS [Extra], 
[Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
[Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Extent1].[Zip] AS [Zip], 
[Extent1].[UpdateTimeStampUtc] AS [UpdateTimeStampUtc], 
[Extent1].[UpdateUserGUID] AS [UpdateUserGUID], 
[Extent1].[UpdateUserID] AS [UpdateUserID], 
[Extent1].[Telephone_TelephoneID] AS [Telephone_TelephoneID]
FROM [Sales].[Address] AS [Extent1]}
```

I'm guessing this is left over from when the table once had this column.  Since I do not know how this query value is created or where it's stored (solution-wide search for "Telephone_TelephoneID" turned up nothing), how can I correct it?

Comment: the edmx may not be refreshed ! please try by refreshing the edmx

Comment: try to update your edmx model

Comment: Try to run SQL Profiler and execute the insert statement to find out error

Comment: remove the navigation property, exclude it from the model or map it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have an EDMX.  This was created via code first from existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, there were elements left over from when Address had a TelephoneID column, and **updating the model's entity classes** solved this.

One clue something was off--and I don't know how I missed this--should have been how the Telephone entity class had this property:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

And of course, this would, if lazy loading is enabled, become populated with Address objects for the Address records that had the Telephone record's TelephoneID.  We now have an AddressShipInfo class that has an AddressID and TelephoneID and implements them as foreign keys, generating this code ("oes" written automatically):

```
[Table("Sales.AddressShipInfo")]
public partial class AddressShipInfo
{
    ...
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Telephone Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("Sales.Address")]
public partial class Address
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Address()
    {
        AddressShipInfoes = new HashSet<AddressShipInfo>();
    }
    ...
    public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AddressShipInfo> AddressShipInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("Sales.Telephone")]
public partial class Telephone
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Telephone()
    {
        AddressShipInfoes = new HashSet<AddressShipInfo>();
    }
    ...

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AddressShipInfo> AddressShipInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

So now, of course, one can retrieve an Address or Telephone and with lazy (or eager or explicit) loading have the AddressShipInfo records that refer to it.  Most importantly, Telephone_TelephoneID is no longer part of the Address query!

Thanks to all who responded, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If there are foreign key relationships in the database which aren't handled in your model or model map, I believe EF will attempt to determine (or make up) the column name to use for the relationship.  I think it would be helpful for answering the question to see the model definitions for your telephone and address tables.  If there are foreign key relationships in the database that aren't captured by your model or model map, you'll need to account for those with one of the following options:

1. Use FluentApi to specify a foreign key in the model map

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<YourTable>()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.YourForeignKeyId);
   ```
2. Use the ForeignKey attribute to specify a foreign key in the model class (with a corresponding virtual navigation property)

   ```
   [ForeignKey("YourForienKeyColumn")]
   public virtual YourTable YourTable { get; set; }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but the Address table no longer has any foreign keys.  Please see my edit above.

Comment: If you post your address model class, and any fluentApi code from your model map, that might help diagnose the issue.  I'm still suspicious of some sort of unresolved foreign key relationship (perhaps left over from when the table contained a TelephoneId column?).  For example, after the TelephoneId field was removed from the database, did a virtual navigation property to Telephone get left in the Address model class?